# How to set up the recurrence for specific times during a week?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a event `activity` that I want to put on calendar. `activity` has a `start date`, an `end date`, and 7 different times for every weekday. Now I want to set up the calendar so that `activity` appears at the right time for each day during the week (which are all different) from `start date` to `end date`. However, it seems that `initRecurrenceWithFrequency:interval:daysOfTheWeek:daysOfTheMonth:monthsOfTheYear:weeksOfTheYear:daysOfTheYear:setPositions:end:` does not allow me to specify at what time the activity occurs everyday.

How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create repeating events at regular intervals. In order for you to create events at different times, you need to create multiple events.

Comment: Then how do I only register an event during a certain time period? e.g. the activity only repeats for the next 3 months.

Comment: You set the endDate. Check out the EKRecurrenceRule reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: How about a different start date other than today?

Comment: Create an NSDate for the date you want the event to start, then you set the startDate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKEvent/startDate

Comment: I'm confused. What's the difference between EKEvent endDate and EKRecurrenceRule recurrenceEnd?

Comment: An EKEvent is the class that represents actual event you are creating. The EKRecurrenceRule describes how that event repeats.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40338/discussion-between-jonah-at-godaddy-and-onezero)